# Why does the Sky Texture have no Inputs?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

Is it possible to get an input for the sky texture, like other textures? As you can see in the picture, there is no input for the sky texture. If it is not possible, why, and if it is, how can I do it? I'm trying to make a full sky node group.

[image]

Comment: The sky texture needs no input. What were you expecting to plug into it?

Comment: I was trying to make a node group that depends on the sun's elevation, making stars come out at night.

Comment: I don't know how you exactly want to create the node group, but would a simple driver not work in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to add inputs to a node, no.  Why?  Because there are only a small number of developers who have to prioritize what they work on and nobody has ever made a strong case for the controls of the Sky Texture node to be settable via external inputs.

One work around would be to write a Python script that created a custom property for each control, and then to write drivers that used the custom properties to set the value of the controls; but that still wouldn't give you the sort of input ability you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of annoying, but I guess I'll deal with it. Thanks for your answer!